# Django backend cannot access Cookies

Tags: django, cookies, cors

Hey I'm trying to access my jwt token in my cookies to do authorization in my backend. But when trying to access my cookie from the request I receive an empty dict. The cookie is created like this in my frontend.
`cookies.set("jwttoken", result.data.token, { path: "/", maxAge: 3600});`
this is done using the `universal-cookie` npm package. In my backend I try to access my cookies like this.
`jwt = request.COOKIES.get("jwttoken")` But receive `None` when trying to print the token.
This is everything `CORS` related in my settings.py

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

CSRF_USE_SESSIONS = False
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False
CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
    "https://********-*******.******.com",
    "https://www.******.com"
]
```

Thanks for all the help

Comment: I think you need to send the token in a header

Comment: yes indeed i put the access token in the header and retrieve it like this `request.headers["Authorization"]` thanks